# Is there a way to avoid sending duplicate email alerts?

Tags: email-alert, notification, duplicate-management

I handle our support cases. I have a workflow rule that when a case is updated it sends a notification to the Case Owner and to the manager of the Account. Sometimes these two people are different, but sometimes they are the same. If they are the same I would like to only send one copy of the email, not two.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I used a "Set a condition" event at the start of my workflow. It checks the "Created By" field in the List Item against the "Manager" field in the List Item.

I put a notification in the "YES" result so that if the two values match, it sends an email to the "Created By" user.

In the "NO" result, I put a notification that sends an email to both the "Created By" and "Manager" values.

Answer (score 1):

On mobile so apologies for brevity and/or typos. Can you access the manager user id in a workflow rule entry criteria ? If so, try setting up a workflow rule to notify the case owner as desired, and then another rule to send same email to manager only if managerID not equal to caseOwnerId. Havent tried so just a stab in the dark sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Using workflows? Sorry, no.

Using Apex? Create a set to hold your email addresses, which will eliminate duplicates automatically.